# Node.js How to save data from pg database into variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, chart.js

How to retrieve data into variables and insert them into specific places so that it can read this data?

I have db.js file

```
const pg = require('pg');
const conString = "postgres://name:password@tai.db.elephantsql.com/name";
const client = new pg.Client(conString);

client.connect()

const query = `SELECT name FROM labels`;

let labelsFromDb = [];

client.query(query, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    for (let row of res.rows) {
        labelsFromDb.push(row);
    }
    for (let row of labelsFromDb) {
        console.log(row);
    }
    client.end();
});
```

and after execute "node db.js" i have response in console

```
{ name: 'lab_1' }
{ name: 'lab_2' }
{ name: 'lab_3' }
```

what is actually data from database and it is correct.

Now what i want to do it save this data into a variable. I have

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('radar');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type : 'radar',
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            label: "data_0",
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 255, 132, 0.2)"]
        }]
    }
});

function addData(){...}
function removeData(){...}
```

I'd like to save my data from db to variable and put it into "labels:" instead empty array. is it possible? How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace your empty labels array with the values of the objects, you can achieve this using a map like so:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('radar');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type : 'radar',
    data: {
        labels: labelsFromDb.map((el) => el.name),
        datasets: [{
            label: "data_0",
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 255, 132, 0.2)"]
        }]
    }
});

function addData(){...}
function removeData(){...}
```

Comment: of course but labelFromDb is empty :/ values in labelFromDb exists only in  client.query(....etc)